# SAP Crystal Reports send null/hide else show number

Tags: c#, .net, crystal-reports, crystal-reports-8.5

I want to show the sum of a Numeric column in Crystal reports but hide if 0.

Tried:

- ```
  IIF ( ToNumber({Choice_.Choice1}) > 0 , true, false)
  ```

  Gives Count. Need Sum.
- ```
  NOT(ISNULL({Choice_.Choice1}))
  ```
- ```
  IF( ToNumber({Choice_.Choice1}) > 0) then ToNumber({Choice_.Choice1})
  ```

Still shows the "0" values

Comment: where did you write these formulas. Mention section

Comment: Crystal Report=>Report Header=>Report Fields

Comment: check answer...

Answer (score 0):

```
* IIF ( ToNumber({Choice_.Choice1}) > 0 , true, false) >> Gives Count. Need Sum
```

Since your formula returning a **String** hence in your report you get only count, There won't be sum. If you need sum then return number.

```
   * NOT(ISNULL({Choice_.Choice1}))

   * IF( ToNumber({Choice_.Choice1}) > 0) then ToNumber({Choice_.Choice1})
```

Not sure why you wrote above code

Edit-------------------------------------------------------------------

Then you wrote it in a wrong place, You need to write the formula in the Supress part of the section expert of the report header instead of report fields.

Go to the supress part of the Report header.

```
Right click on report header --> section expert --? click x->2 of supress
```

and write formula (This is applicable if data is in report header else write the same formula in which ever section where data is present)

So your formula would be

```
ToNumber({Choice_.Choice1}) > 0 //Take care choice1 should always a numeric vallue else report throws exception
```

Comment: thanks Siva, I tried the same formulas you mention too. you can see my posted question. Still able to see the empty values displayed in the chart

Comment: Ohhh sorry overseen your issue... you need to hide something or you want to show sum in report. can you confirm?

Comment: I need to hide the zero values in the chart, to avoid the large empty spaces. and only show the bars with non zero values

Comment: thanks Siva, will definitely try this and revert back